# Minecraft Statistics Json - Java or Python

Tags: java, python, json, minecraft

I am trying to figure out how to read the statistics .json located in **.minecraft/saves/< worldname >/stats/< UUID >.json**

Python Version

```
    import json
    
    json_file = open("C:/Users/<name>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/saves/<worldname>/stats/<UUID>.json")
    variables = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close()
    
    print(variables["stats"])
```

Java Version:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:/Users/<name>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/saves/<worldname>/stats/<UUID>.json")) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            String stats = (String) jsonObject.get("stats");
            System.out.println(stats);

            //long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
            //System.out.println(age);

            // loop array
            //JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
            //Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
            //while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            //    System.out.println(iterator.next());
            //}

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here is roughly what the .json file looks like inside the file:

```
    {'stats': {'minecraft:mined': {'minecraft:lily_of_the_valley': 1, 'minecraft:birch_leaves': 2, 'minecraft:crafting_table': 2, 'minecraft:grass': 1, 'minecraft:grass_block': 4, 'minecraft:oak_log': 10, 'minecraft:dirt': 6, 'minecraft:stone': 6, 'minecraft:oak_leaves': 3}, 'minecraft:killed': {'minecraft:pig': 4}, 'minecraft:picked_up': {'minecraft:stick': 2, 'minecraft:crafting_table': 3, 'minecraft:wooden_pickaxe': 1, 'minecraft:porkchop': 16, 'minecraft:oak_log': 10, 'minecraft:lily_of_the_valley': 1, 'minecraft:dirt': 19, 'minecraft:stone_axe': 1, 'minecraft:stone_pickaxe': 1, 'minecraft:oak_sapling': 2, 'minecraft:birch_sapling': 1, 'minecraft:oak_planks': 16, 'minecraft:cobblestone': 6}, 'minecraft:custom': {'minecraft:time_since_rest': 2832, 'minecraft:sprint_one_cm': 26594, 'minecraft:damage_taken': 360, 'minecraft:walk_one_cm': 10606, 'minecraft:mob_kills': 4, 'minecraft:drop': 1, 'minecraft:damage_dealt': 390, 'minecraft:swim_one_cm': 6359, 'minecraft:interact_with_crafting_table': 2, 'minecraft:fly_one_cm': 37248, 'minecraft:crouch_one_cm': 459, 'minecraft:play_one_minute': 6532, 'minecraft:deaths': 1, 'minecraft:sneak_time': 460, 'minecraft:walk_under_water_one_cm': 38, 'minecraft:jump': 293, 'minecraft:leave_game': 1, 'minecraft:walk_on_water_one_cm': 521, 'minecraft:time_since_death': 2811, 'minecraft:fall_one_cm': 9542}, 'minecraft:dropped': {'minecraft:birch_sapling': 1}, 'minecraft:crafted': {'minecraft:wooden_sword': 1, 'minecraft:oak_planks': 40, 'minecraft:crafting_table': 1, 'minecraft:stick': 8, 'minecraft:wooden_pickaxe': 1, 'minecraft:stone_pickaxe': 1, 'minecraft:stone_axe': 1}, 'minecraft:used': {'minecraft:oak_planks': 27, 'minecraft:wooden_pickaxe': 6, 'minecraft:stone_axe': 7, 'minecraft:wooden_sword': 13, 'minecraft:lily_of_the_valley': 1, 'minecraft:crafting_table': 2, 'minecraft:porkchop': 4}}, 'DataVersion': 2586}
```

So I would like to know how to access each variable in each section in either Java or Python and that will direct me in the path I will take to make my Statistics Reader. I am making a statistics reader program for my Software, Design and Development class and I can't figure out how to access further into the .json file than just what is inside the "stats" element. so in general I would like the program to be able to sort each variable into their sub-headings ("minecraft:mined") and then be able to get variable in that subheading by a search later on, but I will get to that later, I just need to figure out how to read and use the .json file. Thanks for any help that people give me, even if it is a hint in the right direction on researching for myself how to do this because I don't know where to start.

Anyways, thank you guys for your help!

Comment: in python you can just do: `variables["stats"]["minecraft:mined"]["minecraft:lily_of_the_valley"]` and the output should be `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.load()` turns json into python dicts and lists, hence you can work with that data just as you would with regular python data structures. (In case you need to freshen up on those, consider searching for `python list` and `python dict`.)

So basically, in your example, what you could do to get started is:

```py
stats = variables['stats']
# see what that gets you
print(stats)

mined = stats['minecraft:mined']
# once more, see what that is
print(mined)

# and so forth:
print(f"stone: {mined['minecraft:stone']}")
```

from there you should be able to continue on your own. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me!

I can't believe it was that simple, thank you so much and that really helped me get under way with my assignment!

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's solved i think it would be good for you to see it in Java as well. Take a look at this example [Java-Json](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm).

For simplicity sake i changed the data to
`{'stats': {'minecraft:mined': {'minecraft:lily_of_the_valley': 1}}}`

The approach would be something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

    String s = "{\"stats\": {\"minecraft:mined\": {\"minecraft:lily_of_the_valley\": 1}}}";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(s);

    JSONObject base = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONObject stats = (JSONObject) base.get("stats");
    JSONObject minecraft_mined = (JSONObject) stats.get("minecraft:mined");
    long minecraft_lily_of_the_valley = (long) minecraft_mined.get("minecraft:lily_of_the_valley");
    System.out.println(base);
    System.out.println(stats);
    System.out.println(minecraft_mined);
    System.out.println(minecraft_lily_of_the_valley);


  }
```